# I have a weird boot problem and haven't found a way to fix it!

Tags: boot

I have only installed ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and it worked fine for a month, but now it's not booting every time properly. I see the bios logo and a after that a black screen and the bios logo again. When the boot finally works after (after several tries) comes the screen that ask if you want to fix linux boot.

Fixing works but ubuntu and bios lose the time. Onetime my computer didn't boot at all but when I connected it to the AC power it booted and again the boot repair. Is this a software problem or could it be a hardware problem? My computer has UEFI could that have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands and see if it fixes it.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb (replace /dev/sdb with your own drive)
sudo update-grub
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Haven't had boot problems after those commands.

Comment: I wasn't sure it worked because its quite random when the boot fails.  I was afraid it would appear again at it did.

Comment: try disabling UEFI boot, update bios, run a RAM test, and ran a HDD sector test.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you  running ?

Comment: Im running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. By disabling UEFI you mean legacy boot mode? As for RAM test I don't know how to run it because I can't access the grub on boot by pressing shift.

Comment: put it in legacy boot mode and run those commands.

Comment: boot from live CD or USB. Press and hold any key while your computer is booting.
Press 'F6', a language menu will pop up, select English and press enter. You will then be presented with the option menu. test memory will be there.